# How are credentials passed from an IIS server to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, security, web, iis-7.5

This may sound elementary, but I have to answer questions from an auditor. We have a standard IIS Asp.Net site using SQL Server. We have encrypted the connection strings in `web.config`, but it seems to me this only protects the `web.config` file itself, since decryption is done right on the same IIS machine for ASP.Net to use to authenticate to SQL Server.

The question I'm being asked, and have never given it much thought, is: when IIS authenticates with SQL Server, are the now decrypted credentials sent to SQL Server in cleartext? Or is there some sort of out-of-the-box standard encrypted method in which IIS authenticates with SQL Server? If so, how strong is the method used?

Thanks,
James

Comment: AFAIK connection string data is not encrypted between sql server and sql client (iis in your case), that's why windows authentication is considered more secure, since passwords are not being sent between sql server and client.

Comment: Depends on [how it is configured](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: What do you mean by IIS connects to SQL Server? Some code is doing that for you yes? What are you using for that.

Comment: @Admiral Adama -- I'm talking about the authentication process that happens using the sql-server (not Windows) user/pwd stored in the web.config file.  IIS has to present these to the sql-server box and get a response, I was asking if that conversation is done in cleartext.